# How to unload data of syscat.tables on my prod db on instance1

Tags: db2-luw

how to unload data of syscat.tables on my prod db on instance1 on some host  and load this data to my dev db on instance2 on another host  and then I want to compare list of table names on dev db so that i can correct my table definitions.

Do we have to use load and unload command
let me know if i am not clear

Answer (score 1):

If you're only comparing table names and not much else, you can unload that information to a text file via the [EXPORT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html) command.

`db2 "EXPORT TO tablenames.csv OF DEL SELECT tabschema, tabname FROM syscat.tables ORDER BY tabschema, tabname"`

Another way to capture the output of a SELECT statement is with the `-z` option of the [command line processor](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010410.html) (CLP).

`db2 -z tablenames.txt "SELECT tabschema, tabname FROM syscat.tables ORDER BY tabschema, tabname"`

That said, any serious effort to compare and contrast the table definitions of different DB2 databases should involve the [db2look](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002051.html) command, which can reverse-engineer just about any DB2 object into a set of DDL statements. I highly recommend it.

Regardless of how you decide to generate the details about each database, you're likely to have a much easier time comparing them as text files than as rows inside a database. The [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility) command has been around for over forty years, and newer implementations such as [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) and [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com) will make quick work of identifying discrepancies in even the largest sets of text files.